# Error in Netlogo foreach when trying to find the diff between two list items

Tags: foreach, netlogo

I am trying to take the difference per position of two arrays and put them in a third array:

```
let list1 [ 3 4 5 ]
let list2 [ 6 7 8 ]
let list3 [ ]

( foreach list1 list2 [
  [ a b ] -> lput ( a - b ) list3
] )
```

Ideally, I would have `list3` be `[ -3 -3 -3 ]` after.

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
FOREACH expected this input to be an anonymous command, but got an anonymous reporter instead
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried putting parenthesis around the function, but I'm very new to NetLogo.

Note: I'm using NetLogo 6.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can make your `foreach` work like this:

```
  let list1 [ 3 4 5 ]
  let list2 [ 6 7 8 ]
  let list3 [ ]

  ( foreach list1 list2 [
    [ a b ] -> 
    set list3 lput ( a - b ) list3 
  ] )
```

However, `map` is probably the better primitive in this case:

```
  let list1 [ 3 4 5 ]
  let list2 [ 6 7 8 ]
  let list3 ( map [ [ a b ] -> a - b ] list1 list2 ) 
  print list3
```

**Edit for visibility:**

Nicolas Payette pointed out in the comment below that the more concise syntax of the `map` primitive would be:

```
let list3 ( map - list1 list2 )
```

Comment: +1 for using `map` instead of `foreach`. Note that this is a case where you could use concise syntax and pass the `-` operator directly as your anonymous reporter: `let list3 (map - list1 list2)`. See the [programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures) for more detail.

Comment: @NicolasPayette thank you for the clarification / improvement!